# How do I connect two tables in SQL to create a new table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

What I am trying to do is add a section the website that automatically assigns a department to a product when an administrator creates a product. For example, if I create a "t-shirt" product then it gets assigned the the "shirts" department.  I need to get the tables connected in the db so that when a department is loaded, all the associated products show up. When I run a join between the two tables this is what I am running:

```
select d.Name, p.Name
       from products p
        inner join departments d on p.Id = d.Id
```

And I'm getting my only two products which I've manually assigned a department.

Can I get some help with what I need to do next to get every product automatically associated with a department?

Comment: How are you manually linking these two tables? Is there any foreign key between these two tables?

Comment: How do **you** know that `t-shirt` belongs to `shirts` department?

Comment: Could you post the schema of the 2 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select d.Name, p.Name
       from products p
        inner join departments d on p.Id = d.Id
```

you use wrong key to link, (on `p.Id = d.Id`) try on `p.Id= d.foreign_key`